# How to replace the last "/" with a dash in a URL

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have this URL in a Sinatra-based application:

```
<li><a href="/blog/<%= blog.title.tr(' ', '-') %>/<%= blog.slug %>"
             method="get">Show</a></li>
```

When I click on it, the URL looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9292/blog/A-lovely-day/654790
```

I am trying to make the last `/` also a `-` too, so it will be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9292/blog/A-lovely-day-654790
```

How do I replace it after the URL has been rendered?

Comment: ***"after the url has been rendered"*** is a little ambiguous here. Why after?

Comment: I think the manipulation of the URL should occur in a controller, rather than the view.

Comment: @theTinMan I manipulated the url both in the controller and the view at the end.

Comment: @ndn I was rendering a view and it was not fetched properly because of the url change. I wasn't sure if the `/` is incredibly necessary for the `routing` system as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you started with:

[image: original url generation with colors]

The slash is not part of the title, but simply the character in red. Replace it with `-` in the code:

[image: url generation with slash replace with dash]

Comment: Rather than use images use text. It's impossible to use an image for copying and pasting into code unless it's OCR's first.

Comment: @theTinMan it's not the sort of code that you should copy paste, rather than one that explains the problem. The reason I used images is because of the colours.

Comment: I upvoted despite the colour being wrong. It's reddish-orange, not "red".

Comment: This was what I came up with at the end. I modified the `get request` in my Sinatra app accordingly.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, the palette is `#375e97`, `#ffbb00`, `#fb6542`, `#3f681c` in case you are interested. It gives a nice blueish/yellowish/reddish/greenish feel without the sharp contrast of the default `blue`/`yellow`/`red`/`green`. ☺

Answer (score 0):

You can specify more than one character to transform

```
blog.title.tr(" /", "-")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    .*  # match any character zero or more times (greedily)
    \K  # forget all matches so far
    \/  # match a forward slash
    /x  # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

To return a new string with the replacement:

```
blog.title.sub(r, '-')
```

To make the replacement in the existing string:

```
blog.title.sub!(r, '-')
```

One could use capture groups in place of `\K`:

```
blog.title.sub(/(.*)\/(.*)/, '\1-\2')
```

Another way to make the replacement in the existing string:

```
blog.title[blog.title.rindex('/')] = '-'
```

Comment: Not knowing Sinatra (or Rails) I took a chance that my understanding was correct, namely, that it was the last forward slash of `blog.title` was to be replaced. It appears that assumption was incorrect. I will leave my answer, content to receive downvotes, as it addresses a common question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about this:

```
require 'uri'

title = 'A lovely day'
slug = '654790'

uri = URI.parse('http://127.0.0.1:9292/blog/')
[*title.split, slug].join('-') # => "A-lovely-day-654790"
uri.path += [*title.split, slug].join('-')

uri.to_s # => "http://127.0.0.1:9292/blog/A-lovely-day-654790"
```

Generate the URL in the controller and only output the variable in the view.

It's always good to use the built-in tools. URI helps when manipulating URLs/URIs, and understands appropriate encoding if necessary.

Also, it's useful to remember that the `path` is actually a file pathname, so sometimes the File package can be very useful for manipulating/splitting/joining. This wasn't a good example, but it's come in very handy.

Answer (score 0):

```
'http://127.0.0.1:9292/blog/A-lovely-day/654790'.
  sub(/\/(?!.*\/)/,'-') # match a / that is not followed by another /
#=> "http://127.0.0.1:9292/blog/A-lovely-day-654790"
```